# How do included columns in a NONCLUSTERED INDEX affect index fragmentation?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I am learning about indexes and a question popped up about database/index fragmentation when using non-key columns vs key-columns.

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Persons_Name ON Persons (LastName, FirstName)
vs
CREATE INDEX IX_Persons_Name ON Persons (LastName) INCLUDE (FirstName)
```

How does a non-key column affect an index's fragmentation? Is it better to use it as a key column in a simple scenario like above?

Comment: I can't see how/why an included column would have any impact on fragmentation.

Comment: From what I understood from reading on the internet there shouldn't be any impact on fragmentation, but as I am just learning about indexes, I thought I could be missing something. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: I recommend this book, easy to read, clear and usefull: https://www.manning.com/books/learn-sql-server-administration-in-a-month-of-lunches

Comment: Thanks for the book suggestion. Will give it a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes. It all depends on the nature of the include columns. I just ran the following test:

```
create table FragTest (ID int, SID int, data varchar(500));

insert into FragTest (ID, SID, data)
select Number, Number, 'a' from dbadmin.dbo.Numbers
where Number <= 1000000;

create unique clustered index CIX on FragTest (ID);
create index IX on FragTest (SID) include (data);

select * from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(
   db_id(), 
   object_id('dbo.FragTest'), 
   null, null, 'detailed');

update dbo.FragTest set data = replicate('a', 500);

select * from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(
   db_id(), 
   object_id('dbo.FragTest'), 
   null, null, 'detailed');
```

So in essence, I created a table and populated the varchar column with "narrow" data, checked the fragmentation, updated the varchar column with "wide" data, then checked the fragmentation again. Essentially, before the update, the data in the leaf level in the non-clustered index was packed as tightly as it could be for the narrow data. When the update happened, there wasn't room on those leaf level pages to hold the new, wide value and so page splits occurred and fragmentation went up.